# understanding scrollIntoView()

Tags: javascript

I'm really new to this. Please be patient with me. But, is scrollIntoView() built in on chrome? or do i need to create a function for it to work? i don't know if jquery is better to use.

```
function scroll() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById("g[0].sidWORK_ORDER_NOTES");
//g[0].sidWORK_ORDER_NOTES is id of TEXTAREA
  elmnt.scrollIntoView();
}
```

[TEXTAREAimg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Of5uy.png)
attached here is a photo of a program. after i input 3190 and press enter/tab, the cursor is at the word SAMPLE1 but the scroll is at SAMPLE3. how can I scroll on where the cursor is? (SAMPLE1)

Comment: I think it works differently to what you expect. Scroll into view only scrolls if the _textarea_ is not in the viewport. It won’t scroll the content of the textarea

Comment: That Element id looks problematic.

Comment: @evolutionxbox ohh okay. i might have understood it wrong.thank you very much. are there any ways that i can get the scroll the same as where the cursor is?

Comment: I don’t know honestly. The textarea should scroll to where the cursor is when a user starts typing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest :

First check if your **elmnt** actually has the element value of 'SAMPLE1'.

Secondly `scrollIntoView()` function accepts an object with 'block' key that can be given different values like 'start', 'end', 'nearest' etc. You can experiment with these values and see the output behaviour in your UI. As you are doing doing vertical scrolling so 'block' key with one of the value might help you achieve what you are trying to accomplish.

Thirdly, before running scrollIntoView() method check for the element's existence like -

```
if(elmnt) {
scrollIntoView({'block': 'start'});
}
```

Refer below :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView